# Windows phone app - live tile https issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, https, windows-phone

Recently I updated the scheme from http to https in my window phone app. So far network request works fine. 
However, the live tile is not working anymore.
Then I tried to debug and found that:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.ApplicationHost.GetFileSystemPath(String uri)
```

Also:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred Message:
A first chance exception of type
'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' 
occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
invocation.
```

Finally:

```
 at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.ApplicationHost.GetFileSystemPath(String uri)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTileData.GetLocalFilePath(Uri imageUri)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.UriToLocalStoreConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTileData.SerializeToToken(IPMTileInfo token)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile.Update(ShellTileData data)
   at AlarmScheduledTaskAgent.ScheduledAgentSettings.updateLiveTileUI()
```

I know the issue comes from the URI image for liveTile because if I change back to http liveTile is loading the image correctly. Also I tried to use another http image it doesn't crash. But if I use another https image online it crashes.

Although I didn't find anything indicating liveTile doesn't support https, anyone knows how to fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: stupid question but if you go to the https version of the image in a web browser does it load properly without a certificate error?

Comment: It works in a browser. The only issue is that on the client it doesn't work